# CSS How to get floating achors next to eachother horizantal

Tags: css

Mark up as follows

```
     <div class="socialMediaPlugin">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
  </div>
```

And then I was trying

```
.socialMediaPlugin {
float: right;
```

}
But they appear under eachother rather than next ? How could I get them side by side ?

Comment: The container might not be wide enough to fit all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply it to the links, not the container, so you CSS should read

```
.socialMediaPlugin a {
    float: right;
}​
```

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/cDwPb/)

Alternatively you could use

```
.socialMediaPlugin:nth-child(n) {
    float: right;
}​
```

OR

```
.socialMediaPlugin * {
    float: right;
}​
```

although I would not advise it, and it is quite hacky!

Furthermore, you should be using an ordered list for things like that, and you can see an example of that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/cDwPb/2/)

**EDIT based on request from poster**

So that the order of the links can be maintained, it is necessary to wrap the links in a div with `display:block` and float that right instead. See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/cDwPb/3/).

CSS

```
.socialMediaPlugin div {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
​
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it reverses the order of the anchors i.e. the first anchor is now display last etc anyway around that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
.socialMediaPlugin a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

the links will be side-to-side

Comment: and the links will be better-looking if you put something inside the <a></a> like

     <div class="socialMediaPlugin">
       <a class="addthis_button_facebook">Facebook</a>
       <a class="addthis_button_twitter">Twitter</a>
       <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share">G+</a>
       <a class="addthis_button_pinterest" >interest</a>
       <a class="addthis_button_email">E-mail</a>
    </div>

unless you have on your CSS a background, width and height to them. and on IE7 the display: inline-block doesnt work if you use different heights for the links

Answer (score 0):

Since anchors are alreayd inline level elements they'll naturally stack up next to eachother.

The problem is more likely to be that your container isn't wide enough to contain the items stacked up so it's wrapping them.

Either that or you have some other styles applied to your anchor elements that's causing them to act like block level elements.